# How to add a representative color bar for hist2d subplot when scale is different?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add a representative (one instead of two) color bar for 2 hist2d subplots. It is very easy to unite when the scale is same but in my case scale is not same e.g. first color bar upper limit is 6 while for second color bar limit is 14 and so on for other case.
Here is my script:

```
t_arrival=ce['P_Time'];
t_0=t_arrival[70];
t_a=t_0 + timedelta(hours=72);
t_b=t_0 - timedelta(hours=72);

x_bins = np.linspace(-130.05, -129.95, 20);
y_bins = np.linspace(45.90, 46, 20);

df_b = df_lo[(df_lo['A_t'].between(t_b,t_0))];
y_b=df_b['lat'];
x_b=df_b['long'];

df_a = df_lo[(df_lo['A_t'].between(t_0,t_a))];
y_a=df_a['lat'];
x_a=df_a['long'];


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,5), sharey=True)
b=ax1.hist2d(x_b, y_b, bins =[x_bins, y_bins], cmap='Blues')

ax1.set_xlim([-130.05, -129.95])
ax1.set_ylim([45.90, 46])
ax1.set_yticks([45.90, 45.925, 45.95, 45.975, 46])
ax1.set_xticks([-130.05, -130.025, -130, -129.975, -129.95])
cb1=plt.colorbar(b[3], ax=ax1, shrink=0.80)
cb1.set_label('Observations/day', fontsize=10)
ax1.set_ylabel('Latitude', fontsize=10)
ax1.set_xlabel('Longitude', fontsize=10)


a=ax2.hist2d(x_a, y_a, bins =[x_bins, y_bins], cmap='Blues')

ax2.set_xlim([-130.05, -129.95])
ax2.set_ylim([45.90, 46])
ax2.set_yticks([45.90, 45.925, 45.95, 45.975, 46])
ax2.set_xticks([-130.05, -130.025, -130, -129.975, -129.95])
cb2=plt.colorbar(a[3], ax=ax2, shrink=0.80)
cb2.set_label('Observations/day', fontsize=10)
#ax2.set_ylabel('Latitude', fontsize=10)
ax2.set_xlabel('Longitude', fontsize=10)


plt.tight_layout()
```

Result is here:

[image]

Additionally, I want to normalize my x-scale same as y-scale, I don't know why it changes to 10 power.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to set `vmin` and `vmax` or `norm`. To get these values *before* drawing the histograms, you can do it manually by calling numpy [`hist2d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) to get the histograms and then [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html?highlight=pcolormesh#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh) with `vmax` obtained from both histograms.
2. You can switch off the offset notation using [`set_useOffset`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=set_useoffset#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter.set_useOffset)
3. Better use [`constrained`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html) layout to get two equally sized charts and one colorbar.

Minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_bins = np.linspace(-130.05, -129.95, 20);
y_bins = np.linspace(45.90, 46, 20);

x_a = [-130] * 14
y_a = [45.95] * 14
x_b = x_a[:6]
y_b = y_a[:6]

h_a, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x_a, y_a, bins=[x_bins, y_bins])
h_b, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x_b, y_b, bins=[x_bins, y_bins])
norm = plt.matplotlib.colors.Normalize(np.min((h_a, h_b)), np.max((h_a, h_b)))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,5), sharey=True, sharex=True, layout='constrained')

cm_b = ax1.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, h_b.T, norm=norm, cmap='Blues')
cm_a = ax2.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, h_a.T, norm=norm, cmap='Blues')

ax1.set_xlim([-130.05, -129.95])
ax1.set_ylim([45.90, 46])
ax1.set_yticks([45.90, 45.925, 45.95, 45.975, 46])
ax1.set_xticks([-130.05, -130.025, -130, -129.975, -129.95])
ax1.xaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
ax1.set_ylabel('Latitude', fontsize=10)
ax1.set_xlabel('Longitude', fontsize=10)
ax2.set_xlabel('Longitude', fontsize=10)

cb = fig.colorbar(cm_a, ax=ax2, shrink=0.80)
cb.set_label('Observations/day', fontsize=10)
```

[image]